# Paypal Adaptive Payments and Webhook Events Not Registering

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-webhooks

Hello SO PayPal Community.

I'm having trouble getting PayPal to send me "Webhook Events" notifications from an embedded payment flow using Adaptive Payments even though I have registered for all event types.

First off, when I use PayPal's webhook simulator to send me mock notifications to my ngrok.io url I'm able to receive the incoming POST request and subsequent JSON just fine.

Secondly, when I use PayPal's Express Checkout web page PayPal notifies me when a sale has completed. It can be verified on the PayPal developer dashboard in the transactions and webhook events section.

When I embed the Adaptive Payments form below, the user is taken through the PayPal process just fine. Everything works as expected - from User Login to the Payment Success page. However, there is no notification sent. Nothing registers in the developer dashboard in the notifications, transactions or webhook events section. The code is below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
    <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/dg.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
        #submitBtn{
            position:relative;
            top:200px;
            left:40%;
            height:50px;
            width: 200px;
            font-size: 22px;
            border:3px solid #666;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay" target="PPDGFrame" class="standard">
<input type="image" id="submitBtn" value="Pay with PayPal"> 
<input id="type" type="hidden" name="expType" value="light">
<input id="paykey" type="hidden" name="paykey" value="AP-XXXXXXXXXX">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var embeddedPPFlow = new PAYPAL.apps.DGFlow({trigger: 'submitBtn'});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help is sincerely appreciated. I'm going nuts here.

- K

Answer (score 2):

Just received a message from Jennifer at PayPal's Global Tech Support team on the PayPal tech site. Apparently, Adaptive Payments don't trigger REST API notifications, only IPN notifications.

Here's the full message from Jen:

Thank you for contacting PayPal Merchant Technical Support.

Webhooks works with Rest API events only. Rest API will not communicate with Adaptive Payments.

Adaptive Payments is using Classic API. In order to receive event notifications, you will need to integrate Instant Payment Notifications.

Information on IPN'S:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/

"Payments received, including Express Checkout, and Adaptive Payments. "

Integration Guide:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/

IPN Variables:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/

IPN Simulator:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_ipn/